# How do loop through an array that contains all numbers between two integers in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, fizzbuzz

What I want to do is run a "fizzbizz" function using any array of integers that go from `start` to `end` consecutively, then output an array of objects, either integers or strings, according to each case below.

In this example, I'm attempting to run the function on an array that goes from a `start` integer of 1, to an `end` integer of 15.

As the fizzbuzz function goes, for every integer in that range, I want to check to see if it's divisible by 3 and/or 5. If it's divisible by 3 and not 5, I want to return "Fizz", if it's not divisible by 3 but is by 5, I want to return "Buzz", and so on.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set `numsarray` to contain all numbers between the two inputs of the function, `start` and `end`, what I have in that array below is psuedocode. When I try it with an array of specific numbers, all the `return`s in each `case` give me an error stating that I can't convert that expression to that of type `[Any]`.

I use `[Any]` because I'll be pushing both integers and strings into the array, so I don't want to make it one specific type.

```
func fizzinAndBuzzin(start: Int, end: Int) -> [Any]{

    let numsarray = [start...end]

    for number in numsarray {
        switch (number % 3 == 0, number % 5 == 0) {
        case (true, false):
            return "Fizz"
        case (false, true):
            return "Buzz"
        case (true, true):
            return "FizzBuzz"
        default:
            return int(start)
        }
    }  
}

fizzinAndBuzzin(1, 15)
```

Comment: Looping through all the numbers in the array would be pointless since you're going to `return` on the first iteration of the loop no matter what...

Comment: @nhgrif that's a good point. What would be a better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function's return type is `[Any]`, which is an array of any. You are not returning arrays, you are returning single objects. Change your function definition like this:

```
func fizzinAndBuzzin(start: Int, end: Int) -> Any {
```

And then your code doesn't make much sense. Is your goal to return

```
[1,2,"fizz",4,"buzz","fizz",7,8,"fizz","buzz"]
```

etc.

If so then you don't want a return in each case, you want to build an array:

```
func fizzinAndBuzzin(start: Int, end: Int) -> [Any]
{
    //Create an empty array of Any
    var numsArray = [Any]()

    for number in start...end 
    {
        switch (number % 3 == 0, number % 5 == 0) {
        case (true, false):
            numsArray.append("Fizz")
        case (false, true):
            numsArray.append("Buzz")
        case (true, true):
            numsArray.append("FizzBuzz")
        default:
            numsArray.append(number)
        }
    }  
    return numsArray
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `map` function is designed precisely for this purpose, namely taking an array, applying a closure to each of the elements, and creating a new array from that. For example:

```
let foo = [1, 2, 3]
let bar = foo.map { number -> Int in
    return number * 2
}
```

That would assign `bar` to:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

So, applying `map` to your original question, it would look like:

```
func fizzinAndBuzzin(start: Int, end: Int) -> [Any] {
    let numsarray = Array(start ... end)
    return numsarray.map() { number -> Any in
        switch (number % 3 == 0, number % 5 == 0) {
        case (true, false):
            return "Fizz"
        case (false, true):
            return "Buzz"
        case (true, true):
            return "FizzBuzz"
        default:
            return number
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears your intent is to build an array with the "Fizz Buzz values" between start and end, inclusive.  So with that in mind, we don't need to create a `let` array, but instead an empty `var` array and fill it up.

Our `switch` statement should load values into this array.  But I'd actually opt for some abstraction here, so first, a function to just take a single `Int` and return the appropriate value:

```
func fizzBuzzify(value: Int) -> Any {
    switch (value % 3, value % 5) {
    case (0, 0):
        return "FizzBuzz"
    case (0, _):
        return "Fizz"
    case (_, 0):
        return "Buzz"
    default:
        return value
    }
}
```

Now, let's fix our `fizzinAndBuzzin` function:

```
func fizzinAndBuzzin(start: Int, end: Int) -> [Any] {
    var values = Array<Any>()
    values.reserveCapacity(end-start+1)

    for index in start...end {
        values.append(fizzBuzzify(index))
    }

    return values
}
```

This approach preallocates the entire array's memory all in one go (we know before hand *exactly* how big it will be).  This will make a very noticeable difference for very large `start`-`end` deltas compared to approaches with rely on `.append`.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you pre-fill the array with zeros, then go back and install the "fizzBuzzified" result over each zero? So you can use array indexing rather than array.append? If the goal is to avoid the array resizing itself constantly. In that case I'd use reserveCapacity().

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, that's why.  I just edited answer.  I couldn't find the constructor overload for this... didn't realize it was an instance method.

Comment: I know. Seems like there should be a convenience initializer like NSMutableArray's arrayWithCapacity.

Comment: Your edit isn't quite right though. In swift you can't use indexing to add a new object to an array like you can in Objective-C, and reserveCapacity allocates storage, but doesn't fill the array with items, so that code will probably crash. If you're going to switch to using reserveCapacity, you have to also switch to using `values.append()`. (I edited you answer.)

Comment: Do you know if Swift arrays allocate space for items in blocks? I would expect them to, since memory allocations are done in blocks anyway. That would reduce the performance hit of repeatedly appending to an array that starts out empty.